# Google Map API list of cities in certain country

Tags: google-maps

I was wondering if I can see the list of available cities in a certain country in particular the 'short_name' field that google map returns. The reason that I want to know this is that I just want to see the possibilities that google will fill in my geo location

```
function writeAddressName(latLng) {
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
geocoder.geocode({
    "location": latLng
},
function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK)
        document.getElementById("location").value = results[0].address_components[6].short_name;       
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no such functionality available via Google Maps APIs.

Also, you shouldn't rely on the exact position in the address components array:

`results[0].address_components[6].short_name`

Instead, you have to loop over address components array and find one that has 'locality' in the types field.